# REST API for SP 2010 Enterprise search

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

How may I be able to use a ReST API to use the enterprise search on SP2010? I am not talking about the ReST API in each and every SP site.

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 you only have the option of the SOAP Web service. _vti_bin/search.asmx. REST for Search was introduced in 2013. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no REST API for SP 2010 Enterprise Search. SharePoint 2010 REST API is limited to SharePoint Foundation (SPF).